Facing issues in nested routes in Vue-3
I am creating a simple CRUD application for users based on different roles, but I'm facing issues with nested routes and component rendering. I have carefully reviewed their official documentation, but I haven't found a solution. Can anyone help me fix this?
// Component importing perfectly. I have checked one by one on other routes  
{
  path: '/users/:role',
  component: { 
    template: '<router-view></router-view>' 
  }, // This acts as a wrapper component
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      name: "Users List",
      component: NUsers,
    },
    {
      path: "new-user",
      name: "Create User",
      component: UsersCreate,
    },
    {
      path: 'edit-user/:id',
      name: 'Edit User',
      component: UsersEdit,
      props: true // Pass route params as props to the component
    }
  ],
  props: true // Pass route params as props to the component
},


Usage
I'm using  as follows:
<li class="nav-item">
  <sidenav-collapse navText="Manufacturer" :to="{ name: 'Users List', params: { role: 'manufacturer' } }">
    <template #icon>
      <CustomerSupport :color="'#000'"/>
    </template>
  </sidenav-collapse>
</li>

The  component is implemented with  like this:
<router-link class="nav-link" :to="to" v-bind="$attrs">

I'm encountering an issue where navigating to http://localhost:8080/users/manufacturer/ in my Vue.js application does not render anything. However, when I define my Vue Router configuration like this:
{
  path: '/users/:role',
  component: NUsers, // This acts as a wrapper component
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      name: "Users List",
      component: NUsers,
    },
    {
      path: "new-user",
      name: "Create User",
      component: UsersCreate,
    },
    {
      path: 'edit-user/:id',
      name: 'Edit User',
      component: UsersEdit,
      props: true // Pass route params as props to the component
    }
  ],
  props: true // Pass route params as props to the component
}

It renders the NUsers component on all child routes. Not picking child components
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why navigating to /users/manufacturer/ specifically does not render the NUsers component, while other routes such as /users/manufacturer/new-user and /users/manufacturer/edit-user/1 render as expected.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Any errors or weird errors in the Vue devtools regarding the routes?

@kissu check that link https://postimg.cc/QHPLkmQP

@kissu with adding  <router-view></router-view> by making a new component navigation become true but facing many other issues

What about the routes tab of those devtools? What are the other issues?
